# Guest wifi can scan and see all devices on my network on my netgear r6700AX

Tags: networking, router

I have just bought a Netgear r6700AX router.

I have enabled a guest wifi and unchecked "Allow guest to see each other and access my local network".

I have connected to the guest wifi on my phone and I scan devices on my network using fing.. I can see every single device with their names connected to my network.

I can't seem to be able access/ping them tough.

But is it normal that I can discover them? Is there a way to prevent guest wifi discovering the devices on my network and even better be on a separate subnet?

I just found out guesst wifi can't access the internet. bummer

My netgear r6700AX is connected to my ISP router providing the internet (not connected to the WAN port). Probably "Allow guest to see each other and access my local network" is not allowing internet to passthrough from ISP router to netgear r6700AX? is there a way to let is "passtheough"

Comment: Even for a home networking solution I would assume that  a guest WiFi makes the other network segments invisible. Off-Topic though for ServerFault and voting for migration to SuperUser. - The classic solution: did you power it off and back on again after making the adjustments and before testing?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific about how you have things set up and connected on your home network. You almost certainly need the WAN port of your Netgear R6700AX to be connected via Ethernet to a LAN port of your upstream router, and you need to make sure no other devices on your home network can connect to your upstream router without going through your R6700AX. So all the other LAN ports of the upstream router should be empty, and its Wi-Fi should be switched off.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work.

Short intro: what we commonly call "routers" are in fact a combo of a router, switch and access point. Real router is what connects your LAN to the WAN (the Internet). The switch multiplies router's single LAN port into multiple ports. Access point is connected to the switch and provides WiFi.

All devices connected to the switch, either with cables or through the access point, can communicate with each other.

My best guess is that to enable guest isolation, the router creates a second virtual access point that is routed differently: there's no routing to the LAN, just to the Internet and from the Internet. Except the Internet is expected to come in through the WAN port and that's not the case here. You have it connected to one of the LAN ports and the switch and access point distribute it, the router part is non-functional. Since isolated guests aren't on the LAN, they don't have Internet connectivity.

If you can, put your ISP's router/modem in the bridge mode and connect it through the WAN port, then use Netgear as your main router.